# Can't select element from drop down menu E2E testing using Protractor

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

There's quite a few ways to do this and I've tried a good number of them but I can't select an item from a drop down menu when doing an automated test.

"Select" is the default choice that appears in the drop down menu, I want the automated test to pick one of the elements, doesn't matter which one

This is the HTML Code

```html
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="user.investmentAmount" required="" ng-class="{submitted:invalid}">
                   <option value="">Select</option>
                   <option value="<50"> 50K</option>
                   <option value="50-100">100K</option>
                   <option value="100-250">250K</option>
                   <option value="250-500">500K</option>
                  </select>
```

And this is my Protractor file

```js
var selectDropdownbyNum = function ( element, optionNum ) {
    if (optionNum){
      var options = element(by.cssContainingText("Select"))  
        .then(function(options){
          options[2].click();
        });
    }
  };
  browser.sleep(2000);
```

I've tried using by.cssElement, by.xpath etc.
When I run the above, I get no errors but it doesn't select any element either.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selects are an odd duck for sure. I generally just click the option by text (when possible). Eg. you should be able to do something like this...

```
var selectOptionByText = function(text) {
    return element(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I eventually got a different drop down menu on the same page to work using: 
 `element(by.model('user.sourceOfFunds')).sendKeys('Savings');`                       The above line works fine for me but when I try                                                                      `element(by.model('user.investmentAmount')).sendKeys('50-100');` or           `element(by.model('user.investmentAmount')).sendKeys('100k');`     I get element not visible. Not sure why one works and not the other

Answer (score 0):

Once you clicked on //select[@ng-model='user.investmentAmount'] usng xpath,
Put some wait like "browser.sleep(2000)" then use //option[text()='100K'] to click.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I eventually got a different drop down menu on the same page to work using: 
 `element(by.model('user.sourceOfFunds')).sendKeys('Savings');`                       The above line works fine for me but when I try                                                                      `element(by.model('user.investmentAmount')).sendKeys('50-100');` or           `element(by.model('user.investmentAmount')).sendKeys('100k');`     I get element not visible. Not sure why one works and not the other

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you are selecting only one option containing 'Select' value and expecting array,

> try below, first get the select box by model and get all options by
>   html tag name in array

```
browser.element(by.model('user.investmentAmount')).all(by.tagName('option')).
   then(function(items){
        items[2].click(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I eventually got a different drop down menu on the same page to work using: element(by.model('user.sourceOfFunds')).sendKeys('Savings'); The above line works fine for me but when I try element(by.model('user.investmentAmount')).sendKeys('50-100'‌​); or element(by.model('user.investmentAmount')).sendKeys('100k'); I get element not visible. Not sure why one works and not the other

Comment: It's better to open other question if you have unrelated to it...but for this question either resolve it or close...so that in future other can get benefits from it,,,